# find the corresponding entries between PHP array and JSON object

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have two arrays

```
<?php
 $x=array('store1'=>'A','store2'=>'B' ,...);
?>
```

and

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var x={"srote1": [12,13],"store2":[20,23] ....};
</script>
```

what is the optimal way to find the corresponding entries between these data structures

Comment: The results should be calculated where? What do you want to do with them? What have you tried?

Comment: How do you intend to work with Javascript data in PHP? Is this another "\*sigh\* PHP is server-side, Javascript is client-side" question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
 $x=array('store1'=>'A','store2'=>'B' ,...);
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var x=new Array("store1","store4","store10"); 
  var phpArrayX = <?=json_encode($x)?>;
</script>
```

-> now you can compare these two arrays in javascript (if that's what you need)